# 'No signature of method' when attemptng to set property value in project using Groovy

Tags: groovy

Encountering the following issue when attempting to set a property at project level.

> No signature of method: com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlProject.setPropertyValue() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.math.BigDecimal) values: [TitleId, 1] Possible solutions: setPropertyValue(java.lang.String, java.lang.String), getPropertyValue(java.lang.String)

The code works when i set the project property the first time with 'rs' however the second time it refuses to store it and returns the error message above.

The conditional query is as follow:

```
if (rs !=null) {

log.info ("Result " + (rs[0])) 
project.setPropertyValue("TitleId", rs[0]); //this works
}

else {

def cdsTitle = "SELECT TITLE_TYPE, TITLE_TEXT FROM PARTY WHERE PARTY_KEY ='" + context.expand('${#Project#PartyKey}') + "'";
def titleType= sqlCDS.firstRow(cdsTitle)

project.setPropertyValue("TitleId", titleType[0]); //This is the statement which causes the error message
}
```

'titleType' returns two values and I'm trying to set it to be the first hence the '[0]'. I have tried to store this value in its own variable and use that to set the property however this still faulted with the same error message.

i.e.

```
def cdsTitle = "SELECT TITLE_TYPE, TITLE_TEXT FROM PARTY WHERE PARTY_KEY ='" + context.expand('${#Project#PartyKey}') + "'";
def titleType= sqlCDS.firstRow(cdsTitle)

def ttype = titleType[0]; //returns 1

project.setPropertyValue("TitleId", ttype;) 
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seens that `rs[0]` (as the 2nd argument) has a proper type and (as you wrote) it was accepted.

Then the program goes along the *else* path and uses `titleType[0]`
as the 2nd argument.

Are you sure that it has the same type?

Look thoroughly at the error message:

```
No signature of method: ... is applicable for argument types:
(java.lang.String, java.math.BigDecimal) values: [TitleId, 1]
```

The above message says that:

- the 1st argument was `TitleId` (I assume a string and it was accepted),
- the 2nd argument is `1` (a *BigDecimal* of value 1) and probably there
  is something wrong about the type.

Maybe you should cast it to another type?

Comment: Hi thanks for helping me out. Yes both rs and titletype have the same value i.e. they both get set to a number, the only difference i can see is that rs just has one value stored i.e. {CODE_ALIAS=1} and i retrieve the '1' from it. But titleType has two arguments against it e.g. {TITLE_TYPE=1, TITLE_TEXT=Mr} and I am trying to retrieve '1'

Comment: You wrote that in both cases the **value** is *1*. But what about the **type** of the value retrieved in both cases?

Comment: gets classed as a string. I've managed to make it work by adding titleType[0].toString()  :)

Answer (score 0):

titleType[0].toString() seems to fix the problem